# Is it OK to swallow an exception for DB INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, exception

Is it OK to swallow Duplicate key violation exceptions for INSERTS or should you check if the record exists?

So let's say that I have a table Photo with one field: PhotoName. I'm looking through a file directory to add items to Photo. In the process, it's possible that when I find a photoname, it might already be in the database. So there are two ways to go about this:

```
1) //Look to see if it exists before adding it. Only add it if it does not exist.

bool photoExists = SQLSELECTStatementToCheckIfThePhotoExists(photoName);
if(!photoExists)
  SQLCommandToInsertPhoto(photoName)

or 2) //Assume that it doesn't exist. If it does, catch and ignore.
try
{
  SQLCommandToInsertPhoto(photoName);
}
catch(DuplicateKeyException ex)
{
  //swallow it and continue on as if nothing happened.
}
```

On the one hand, I don't necessarily like the notion of just "swallowing" an exception, but on the other hand, try...catch uses only one call to the DB. This happens to be in SQL Server.

Comment: You may want to look into `MERGE` as that will allow you to match your datasets on that key and only insert where there is not match.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out MERGE. Suppose one is using an ORM that does not have merge capabilities? Thoughts?

Comment: @John [please use caution with `MERGE`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely not just "swallow" the exception. You should be trying to find these duplicates and not insert them if needed.

On method could be checking where not exists on the key.

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable

SELECT 
    KeyID,
    blah,
    blerg,
FROM SourceTable AS S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TargetTable AS T
    WHERE S.KeyID = T.KeyID
    )
```

This method will allow you to only `INSERT` new rows into the table. This method of course does not account for any matching you may need to do for an `UPDATE`, however that's outside the scope of this question but should still be thought about. Most users could also use `MERGE` I'll post an example of that when I get time.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even think to just add a simple NOT EXISTS condition into my statement.

Comment: Since the data is not coming from an existing table, how would this be done using INSERT VALUES ?

Comment: Are these values going one at a time?

Comment: This is incorrect. The construct is not safe to use under concurrency. The SELECT and the INSERT are performed independently from one another by SQL Server and therefore the outcome cannot be guaranteed. It may work well for months .... until it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

It can be very expensive to let SQL Server raise exceptions (even if you only swallow them) - see [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2632/checking-for-potential-constraint-violations-before-entering-sql-server-try-and-catch-logic/?utm_source-AaronBertrand) and [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/error-handling).

So my suggestion is to check for the violation first, and only insert if you have to. However, I wouldn't separate these out into separate statements, especially in completely separate round-trips to the app, as you can have this scenario:

```
-- connection A, at 12:00:00.0000001:

SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE key = 'x'; -- 0 rows returned

-- connection B, at 12:00:00.0000002:

SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE key = 'x'; -- 0 rows returned

-- connection A, at 12:00:00.0000003:

INSERT dbo.TABLE(key) VALUES('x'); -- succeeds

-- connection B, at 12:00:00.0000003:

INSERT dbo.TABLE(key) VALUES('x'); -- fails
```

I would rather do this in a single `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS` statement, as [@Zane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21485328/61305) demonstrates, though I would add higher escalation on the `SELECT` portion. Or you could use an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger to just bail from the insert if a key violation is spotted ([I wrote about this here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3139/improve-sql-server-efficiency-by-switching-to-instead-of-triggers/?utm_source-AaronBertrand).)
As an aside, I'd use extreme caution with `MERGE` - see [this article for my reasoning](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/?utm_source-AaronBertrand) and [some other opinions, too](https://sqlblog.org/merge).

Comment: Good articles. I wouldn't have known about the issues with MERGE. Also, I'll keep in mind using those type of triggers for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Answers using `IF NOT EXIST`, `EXCEPT`, `MERGE`, etc are not correct. They are not safe to use under concurrent load. Your code may work correctly for months and suddenly one day: boom!. You need something which guarantees an atomic action.

Let's review the current state, year 2022, while comparing MS SQL Server to some immediate competitors:

**PostgreSQL**: Native support: `INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`

**MySQL**: Native support: `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...`

**MS SQL Server**: well, hmm, no native support and it quickly gets ugly. The closest thing to native support is the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option on the index, but since you set it on the index, you cannot do it on a per-statement basis. You can do the statement inside a transaction and use SQL Server's lock hints, i.e. `UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE` or a `MERGE` with `HOLDLOCK` hint but it feels a bit like you need to have a PhD in MS SQL Server and I think there's to much of a risk for crafting the statement wrong.

Conclusion for MS SQL Server: In the end doing a try-catch and ignoring a *specific error* isn't a bad idea at all. There may be solutions which perform slightly better if you need to perform a million inserts in one go, but that hasn't been my concern.

YMMV. My basic point is that you need to pay attention to concurrency.

[This article](https://michaeljswart.com/2017/07/sql-server-upsert-patterns-and-antipatterns/) is quite informative, IMO.